# Collecting Data in table

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I wrote a program (with help of the stackexchange) that is supposed to run in a loop. 
Each time the program runs, it exports a small data.
Is it possible to generate a table where each run adds the new data?

I am still working at the loop but here is the programm for so far:

```
direin = SetDirectory[StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "Eingang\\"]];
diraus = StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "Ausgang\\"];
SetDirectory[direin];
files = FileNames[{"*.PNG"}, FileNameJoin[{Directory[]}]];
img = Import /@ FileNames[files[[1]]];
img = img[[1]];
noBorder = ImagePad[img, -BorderDimensions[img]];
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[noBorder];
wnd = Outer[Times, Array[HammingWindow, h, {-.5, .5}], 
   Array[HammingWindow, w, {-.5, .5}]];

rawPixels = ImageData[noBorder][[All, All, 1]];
imgTimesWnd = (rawPixels - Mean[Flatten[rawPixels]])*wnd;

ft = Fourier[imgTimesWnd];
center = Floor[Dimensions[ft]/2];
ft = RotateRight[ft, center];

Image[Rescale[Log[Abs[ft] + 10^-3]]]

(*Winkel*)
brightestOffset = First[Position[Abs[ft], Max[Abs[ft]]]] - center
maxAngle = ArcTan @@ N[brightestOffset/{h, w}]
inDeg = 180 / \[Pi]; 
getDeg = inDeg*maxAngle
namebild = FileBaseName[files[[1]]]
Export[namebild <> "_Winkel.txt", getDeg];
```

Please note that this program is supposed to export a specific angle.

Comment: It isn't really possible to run your code, since I don't have your directory structure and image files, but you essentially create a text file when you run that contains a single angle in degrees?  And you want to be able to run the program many times and write to that same file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than `Export` a single number to a file, open the file as a stream and write to it,

```
ang = RandomReal[2 π] /Degree;
outputfile = OpenAppend["file.txt"]
Write[outputfile, ang]
Close[outputfile]
```

If you run OpenAppend on a file that doesn't exist, it will create it.  Then when you use Write, it writes the content to the file, followed by a newline.  When you open the file again using `OpenAppend`, it will simply write the text on the next line and end in a new line.

Running this loop,

```
Do[
 ang = RandomReal[2 \[Pi]] /Degree;
 outputfile = OpenAppend["file.txt"];
 Write[outputfile, ang];
 Close[outputfile];
 , {20}]
```

generates this file

[image]

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for!!! thx for your help.